# AWS Lambda function returns before function called by IntentHandler completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am developing my first Alexa Skill using AWS Lambda. 
The challenge I have is that Lambda function completes before all sync functions run.
I am using an example below (taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/chrisabrams/11011880)) 
where a function a() calls B() (which I believe will be asynchronous call by default)
When I test my fuction sometimes I get only output
'A is done'
and function returns without executing B(), C(), D()

I am calling A() from my GetUpdateIntent. I have read few posts suggesting to use context.done() in callback
to ensure callback completes. I am not able to follow how to achieve this.
I do like all my callbacks and async calls to complete before lambda function completes.

```
var A = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var result = 'A is done'
        console.log(result)
        resolve(result);      
    })  
}

var B = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var result = 'B is done'

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(result)
            resolve(result);
        }, 2000)
        global_context.done();
    })
}

var C = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var result = 'C is done'
        console.log(result)
        resolve(result);
    })
}

var D = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var result = 'D is done'
        console.log(result)
        resolve(result);
    })
}

A()
.then(function(result) { 
    return B();
})
.then(C)
.then(D)
.then(console.log("All done"));

Example.prototype.intentHandlers = {
    GetUpdateIntent: function(intent, session, response){
        A();
  },
};

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var skill = new Example();
    skill.execute(event, context);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the rest of your functions within your `GetUpdateIntent` function. You need to chain the functions together just like you do before setting up the example class